# Remove Empty URL Param for include_blank with select_tag in form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, url-parameters

When I submit a form to search and display some data, I don't want an empty parameter appearing in the url if the "include_blank" value is selected.

```
<%= form_tag(search_index_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= select_tag(
        'fruit_selection',
        options_for_select(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear'], @prev_fruit_search),
        include_blank: 'All Fruit'
      ) %>
  <%= submit_tag('Search', name: nil) %>
<% end %>
```

I expect/would like:

1. Apple: mysite.com?fruit_selection=Apple
2. Banana: mysite.com?fruit_selection=Banana
3. Pear: mysite.com?fruit_selection=Pear
4. All Fruit: mysite.com

But, instead I get:

1. Apple: mysite.com?fruit_selection=Apple
2. Banana: mysite.com?fruit_selection=Banana
3. Pear: mysite.com?fruit_selection=Pear
4. All Fruit: mysite.com?fruit_selection=

Comment: Is the intended behavior then that if they select the "blank" option mysite.com will show all fruits? You could just have "All fruit" be a query param, like Apple or Banana. The resulting url would be something like mysite.com?fruit_selection=All%20Fruit (or whatever the encoding is). Up to you, but this to me seems clearer for the user what's going to happen.

Comment: Yes that is the intention. You should answer the question so that I can mark it as correct.

Here is what I ended up doing:
    <%= select_tag('fruit_selection', options_for_select(['All Fruit'] + ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear'], @prev_fruit_search || 'All Fruit')) %>

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that. I will leave it as a comment though since I my answer was based on my clarifying question. Glad you figured something out that works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet allows for 'All Fruit' to be the default/first option.

When 'All Fruit' is selected, the url query parameter will appear as 'mysite.com?fruit_selection=All+Fruit' instead of the unaesthetic 'mysite.com?fruit_selection='.

When @prev_fruit_search is not nil, it's value will be selected as the option otherwise 'All Fruit' will be selected.

```
<%= form_tag(search_index_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= select_tag(
        'fruit_selection',
        options_for_select(
          ['All Fruit'] + ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear'],
          @prev_fruit_search || 'All Fruit'
        )
      ) %>
  <%= submit_tag('Search', name: nil) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I've added a more detailed explanation.